# Solve $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin 2x}{4x}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(2x)}{4x}$$

In this form, it would be undefined, so how would you change it so that the denominator would not be $0$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  Have you discussed in class or read in your textbook about $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}$?

Comment: Do you know that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$? Draw pictures.

Comment: I did not know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin (2x)}{4x}=\frac{1}{2} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}=\frac{1}{2}$$

It is known that $\displaystyle\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\sin y}{y}= 1$ (you can prove it using L'Hospital's Rule)

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule would not constitute a proof since we need this limit in order to prove that the derivative of $\sin$ is $\cos$.  There is, however, a canonical proof for this using the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Actually, $\displaystyle \lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin y}y = 1$.

Comment: Oh,yes..I accidentally wrote that it is equal to $0$..

Comment: @Omnom There are many other ways to define $\sin$ and $\cos$ such as the solution to a differential equation and as the inverse function of integrals. In each of these approaches we do not need the limit to prove that the derivative of $\sin$ is $\cos$. I believe the standard definition (as per most real analysis books) is in terms of the exponential function which means again that $\sin$ is readily differentiable. I agree that LH should not be used but it is generally false to call it circular.

Comment: @user157227 I had a similar argument [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720924/why-do-we-require-radians-in-calculus/721019#721019), which I'm not eager to repeat. I will simply state that, to the best of my knowledge, the trigonometric definition of $\sin(x)$ is the more common one to start with, certainly in the context of introductory calculus.

Comment: @Omnom In the context of introductory calculus there are a lot better hairs to split.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative method, you could note that $\sin(2x)=2x+\mathcal{O}(x^3)$.

Then,
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(2x)}{4x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x+\mathcal{O}(x^3)}{4x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{2}+\mathcal {O}(x^2)=\frac{1}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

An unconventional solution would be with Maclaurin series;

The Maclaurin series of $$\frac {\sin(2x)}{4x}$$ is $$\frac 12-\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{x^4}{15}+\mathcal{O}(x^6)$$
All the terms but the $\frac12$ become $0$ so there you go.