# Approximate $\sin 29^\circ$ using differentials

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives, approximation

Using differential find approximate value of $\sqrt[3]{1.02}$

I did this.
We know $f(x_0+\Delta x)-f(x_0)=\frac{df}{dx}(x_0)\cdot\Delta x$

$$f(x)=\sqrt[3]{1+x}$$

$$f(0.02)-f(0)=\frac{df}{dx}(0)\cdot0.02$$

And after calculation I solved.

But the problem I don't know how to solve is approximate using differential $\sin29^\circ$.

Comment: do the same but for the sin function. sin(a+x), when a is a value of sin you know. remember $sin(x+2\pi)=sin(x)$

Comment: The title of the question does not match the body. Can you fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of $\sin (30^\circ) = \sin(\frac\pi6) = 0.5$ is known.

Now you have to convert the angles to radians.

Let $x_0 = \frac\pi6$, $\Delta x = - 1^\circ (\text{in radian}) =- \frac{\pi}{180} $.

And $\frac{df}{dx}(x_0) = \cos(x)_{x_0= \pi/6} $

$\sin(29^\circ)=f(x+x_0) = f(x_0)+\frac{df}{dx}(x_0)\Delta x = \sin\frac\pi6 - (\cos\frac\pi6)\cdot\frac\pi{180} \approx 0.4848$

---

P.S. This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720924/why-do-we-require-radians-in-calculus) has answers for why we should convert degrees to radians in calculus

Comment: I am getting $\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2}$ which is not the answer.

Comment: That's what I've mentioned, you should use $\boxed{\Delta x = - \frac{\pi}{180}}$. I think you've used $\Delta x = -1$ which is in degrees..

Comment: $f(x)=sin(\frac{\pi}{6}+x)$ . $f(\frac{\-pi}{180})-f(0)=\frac{df}{dx}(0)*\frac{\-pi}{180}$ from here not getting the answer.

Comment: @rha I've added it in the answer

Comment: Thanks you very much for your kindness!.