# The radian measure of the angles

Tags: calculus

I have a question about the radian measure of the angles

Why we must use the radian measure when we deal with the trigonometric functions specially in the calculus??

Comment: [Why do we require radians in calculus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720924/why-do-we-require-radians-in-calculus)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we require radians in calculus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720924/why-do-we-require-radians-in-calculus)